# find duplicate data from CSV and merge then in a specific schema

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Context :**

For video editing purpose, I receive CSVs with shot name, start and end timecode.
the interesting CSV datas are formatted this way :

[image: csv data from editor]

the source in / out needs to be converted to a framerange (like 1-24)
so basically a shot is extracted as `sequence('shot','framerange')` like : `SQ010,('010','150-1000').
A sequence can (or not) have multiple shots and multiple time the same shot with a similar or different source in & out. an edit (a CSV) can have multiple sequences

**the problem :**

1/ I'm not able to merge duplicate shots with overlapping framerange in the expected way, that is :

> [ ('SQ010', ('010', '0-81'),('010', '10-250') ), ('SQ020', (...) ) ]

and if the cut of the same shot doesn't overlap, the result must be :

> [ ('SQ010', ('050', '0-65,70-81'),('070', '10-250') ), ('SQ020', (...) ) ]

2/ when I have duplicate shots, I can't run all the scripts we have behind, as they expect unique shot. so i can't (for now) change the expected result formatting

3/ from some reason, some 'None' can appear in the list because of duplicates shots with my code. I don't really understand how to avoid them.

**What I can do for now :**

I'm able to extract sequences, shots, timecode and convert it, but not to merge duplicate shots timecode.

```
import csv
import re
import sys
import os

with open(writeClean, 'r') as clearSL:
    reader = csv.DictReader(clearSL)
    data = {}
    for row in reader:
        for header, value in row.items():
            try:
                data[header].append(value)
            except KeyError:
                data[header] = [value]

# extract from CSV
seqLine = []
shotLine= []
for i in data['Name']:
    if i.startswith('SQ') :
        seq,shot=i.split('_')
        seqLine.append(seq)
        shotLine.append(shot)
    else:
        pass

fInLine=[]
durationTCtoFrame=[]

#read framerate from the first usable shot TODO: do it per shot for precision
framerate = int( float( list( set(data['Source FPS']) )[0] ) )

#convert Timecode to frame
for TC in data['Source In']:
    inTCtoFrame = int(round(tcToFrames(TC,framerate)))
    fInLine.append(inTCtoFrame)

for TC in data['Source Out']:
    duration = int(round(tcToFrames(TC,framerate)))
    durationTCtoFrame.append(duration)


fRange = ["{}-{}".format(*i) for i in zip(fInLine, fOutLine)] #merge first frame and last frame in string format usable by GCC

shotList = list(map(lambda x,y:(x,y),shotLine,fRange))  # merge shotname with framerange
#TEST - print(shotList)
seqInfo = map(lambda x,y:(x,y),seqLine,shotList) # merge sequence and shot
#TEST - print(seqInfo)
seqClean = list(set(seqInfo)) # remove duplicate with set()
seqClean.sort() # order all 
#TEST - print(seqClean)
seqList = [(i,) + tuple(i[1] for i in e) for i, e in groupby(seqClean, lambda x: x[0])] #group shots per sequences
#TEST - print(seqList)
```

this give me this type of result :

> [('SQ010', ('050', '0-81'), ('050', '0-65'),(...)]

if it's help, i can provide a full CSV

thank you

Comment: use `defaultdict(list)`, don't write your own `zip()`

Comment: why and how ? a basic replace return errors : TypeError: first argument must be callable or None

Comment: `zip()` works with iterables, `map(lambda x,y:(x,y),A,B)` == `zip(A,B)`